# Dependency injection and container class (java-ee 7)

Tags: java, containers, cdi, java-ee-7, inject

I am new to DI, but suddenly I need to use it in my EJB application, so I try to remake it.

The approach includes container class that has 2 fields - 2 implementations. It works with one or both implementations depending on a parameter. The container is created in singleton's method call but used by other ejb beans.

Here I need help - how to make SecurityContainer class to work properly with other CDI managed classes (ejb beans) or to become CDI managed itself?

I am giving an old (non-CDI) code how it was and worked. Reading parameter and instantiating the container:

```
@Singleton
public class MySingleton {
    private static final MySingleton instance = new MySingleton();
    private volatile SecurityHelper securityHelper;  // container
    public void setSecurityHelper(SecurityHelper secHelper){ securityHelper=secHelper; }
    public SecurityHelper getSecurityHelper(){ return securityHelper; }     
    /* now it has some @Inject....*/    

    public void start(String passwordP, String passwordH)
          .....
        // application work with one or two implementations of security
        if ("P".equals(DbParams.getServerSecurityFlag()))
            instance.setSecurityHelper(new SecurityContainer(new SecurityHelperImplP(DbWorkerImpl.getInstance(), ResponseBuilderImpl.getInstance()), 
                                null));             
        else 
            instance.setSecurityHelper( new SecurityContainer( new SecurityHelperImplP(DbWorkerImpl.getInstance(), ResponseBuilderImpl.getInstance()), 
                                new SecurityHelperImplH(DbWorkerImpl.getInstance(), ResponseBuilderImpl.getInstance()) ) );
        securityHelper.createSecurity(passwordP, passwordH);
```

Here is container class:

```
public class SecurityContainer implements SecurityHelper {
    private SecurityHelper secPrg;
    private SecurityHelper secHard;
    public SecurityContainer(SecurityHelper secPrg, SecurityHelper secHard){
        this.secPrg=secPrg;
        this.secHard=secHard;
    }
```

Concrete implementation now has to inject DbWorker and ResponseBuilder ejb beans. SecurityHelperImplH looks the same.

```
public class SecurityHelperImplP implements SecurityHelper {
    private SecurityPrg securityPrg = null;

    private DbWorker ora;           // now they are CDI managed
    private ResponseBuilder builder; 

    public SecurityHelperImplP(DbWorker dbworker, ResponseBuilder bld){
        this.ora = dbworker;
        this.builder = bld;
    }
```

I believe I need Qualifiers and maybe a Producer, but cannot connect the dots

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, you go either way - producer OR qualifiers. Both will require some refactoring and to me, it seems producer is a smoother way.
It will allows you to inspect the parameter and tailor the producer object (`SecurityContainer`) to your needs.

First of all, the field with your `SecurityContainer` needs to be an injection point, so add `@Inject`:

```
@Inject
private volatile SecurityHelper securityHelper;  // container
```

NOTE: Remember to remove the setter method, when using CDI, you don't want/need it.

Now as to how we produce it. Your start job is basically doing the job already! All you need is to make it a producer, set the right return type and make sure you get the parameters in place. So, step by step:

1) Producer method parameters

All prameters of producers method are automatically considered as another injectable sources. E.g. you would been to be able to `@Inject String passwordP`). Ouch, that won't work right away and I don't know how you retrieve these parameters exactly.

2) How produce method operates

It is a method CDI invokes **every time** it needs to create an instance. So you will have to make up your mind on **scope of `SecurityHelper`**. Since this is set once in start method of a `@Singleton` I suppose it is something that *does not change* during runtime. In such case, you will likely want `@ApplicationScoped`.

3) How it all looks, then?

Here is a code which should do what you want, assuming I did not misunderstood it:

```
@Produces  // telling CDI this is how it is supposed to create instances of this type
@ApplicationScoped // what scope does the produced bean have?
public SecurityHelper produceSecHelper() {
  // TODO add logic to retrieve these params!
  String passwordP;
  String passwordH;

  SecurityHelper result;
  // application work with one or two implementations of security
  if ("P".equals(DbParams.getServerSecurityFlag()){
      result = new SecurityContainer(new SecurityHelperImplP(DbWorkerImpl.getInstance(), ResponseBuilderImpl.getInstance()), 
                                null); 
  } else {
      result = new SecurityContainer( new SecurityHelperImplP(DbWorkerImpl.getInstance(), ResponseBuilderImpl.getInstance()), 
                                new SecurityHelperImplH(DbWorkerImpl.getInstance(), ResponseBuilderImpl.getInstance()));
  }
  result.createSecurity(passwordP, passwordH);
  return result;
}
```

NOTE: CDI will invoke this method on its own accord. You are not supposed to to this manually and even if you do, it won't be recognized by CDI.

Comment: Where do you suppose to put this producer?

By now I left SecurityContainer as it was. MySingleton now is CDI managed, and other managed beans use securityContainer from mySingleton getSecurityHelper().

Comment: It does not matter, as long as the producer resides inside another CDI bean (so that CDI will be able to find it). From CDI 1.2 spec - `A producer method must be a default-access, public, protected or private, non-abstract method of a managed bean class or session bean class. ` So I say, place it, where it is convenient for you.

Comment: Should I pass SecurityHelperImplP and SecurityHelperImplH as arguments to a Producer or not? I tried to pass them with Qualifiers, but get compilation error

Comment: If you want to have them as params, you need to have a producer for both, with qualifier, since both are of the same type (String). I suppose you have them. I have no idea what compilation error are you getting there. But since it's compilation, you are doing something wrong and your IDE usually tells you what.